# Is there a way to find an integer offset that when added to every value in one numpy array maximizes the amount of matches it has to another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example say I had 2 lists:

```
a = np.array([1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9])
b = np.array([103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109])
```

The value I would want to add would be ~100 to add to list *a* as an offset to match as many possible values to list *b* given the offset.

My current solution is basically

```
best_matches = []
for v1 in a:
    for v2 in b:
        offset = abs(v1 - v2)
        matches = np.intersect1d(a + offset, b)

        best_matches.append((offset, len(matches)))

best_offset = max(best_matches, key = lambda i : i[1]) # find offset that had the most amount of intersections when added to the first array
```

I need to solution to work for rather large lists of values so the solution just needs to be either more efficient or different in approach all together. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent to your answer without loops:

```
o = np.bincount(np.ravel(b[:,None] - a[None,:])).argmax()
l = len(np.intersect1d(b, (a + o)))
```

```
>>> (o, l)
(98, 4)
```

*Updated according to comments of
[@AlexanderS.Brunmayr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15964777/alexander-s-brunmayr) and [@Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405065/blckknght)*

Comment: The actual answer is `(103, 4)` and not `(101, 4)`. You can not just do `np.bincount(b - a).argmax()` where `b-a` is the elementwise subtraction. Instead, you need to subtract all possible combinations of elements in b and a.

Comment: @AlexanderS.Brunmayr. Is it better now? But the response of `argmax` is `(98, 4)`

Comment: You don't need the complicated setup code with `A` and `B`, broadcasting can do that for you with a few slices. Try `b[:,None] - a[None,:]`.

Comment: @Corralien. Sorry for saying (101, 4) is not the "actual" answer, it is indeed one of the many solutions, as is (98, 4). And yes, it's better now :D  I like that answer. (btw, Blckknght, that's so cool, I didn't know you could do that)

Comment: @AlexanderS.Brunmayr, Thanks to you too. I did not know either [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis)